# Считывание и обработка JAVA кода

Tags: java

Для реализации одной идеи необходимо считывать файлы с java кодом, дополнять и редактировать их. Есть ли уже какие-то готовые инструменты, чтобы программным методом определять, где комментарии, где блок определения переменных, где код методов и так далее...

Comment: А как Вы изначально будете определять что в файле есть участки java-кода? Если нужен декомпилятор - так и гуглите: "декомпилятор java кода".

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вы можете посмотреть [исходный код javac](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/). Во-вторых, первая ссылка в Google ведёт на некий [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/). А чтение информации ещё по паре ссылок с первой страницы дарит два дополнительных варианта - [org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Fpackage-summary.html) и [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).